# Using an input value in an href

Tags: 2010, html

I would like to use the value that I get in the 'Title' input field, and append it to the end of my href url.  Do you know how to do that?

```
Title Search: <input name="Title" type="text"/> <a href="/sites/203/qaos/bp/Lists/Process%20Tickets/AllItems.aspx?View={85F52167-8747-4423-B7C6-D97B98F7991E}&amp;SortField=ID&amp;SortDir=Desc&amp;FilterField1=LinkTitle&amp;FilterValue1="><img width="238" height="275" alt="cin2.jpg" src="/sites/203/qaos/bp/SiteAssets/Lists/Process%20Tickets/AllItems/cin2.jpg" style="margin: 5px; width: 179px; height: 135px"/> </a><a><br/><br/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself

```
Title Search: <input name="Title" type="text"/>
<a onclick="location.href=this.href+Title.value;return false;" href="/sites/203/qaos/bp/Lists/Process%20Tickets/AllItems.aspx?View=&amp;SortField=ID&amp;SortDir=Desc&amp;FilterField1=LinkTitle&amp;FilterValue1=">
Image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have html tag so if you what to do in local then you could go for JQuery.

First give unique ID to input control and link.

```
            Title Search: <input id="titleInput" name="Title" type="text"/> <a  id="titleLink" href="/sites/203/qaos/bp/Lists/Process%20Tickets/AllItems.aspx?View={85F52167-8747-4423-B7C6-D97B98F7991E}&amp;SortField=ID&amp;SortDir=Desc&amp;FilterField1=LinkTitle&amp;FilterValue1="><img width="238" height="275" alt="cin2.jpg" src="/sites/203/qaos/bp/SiteAssets/Lists/Process%20Tickets/AllItems/cin2.jpg" style="margin: 5px; width: 179px; height: 135px"/> </a><a><br/><br/></a>
        $(document).ready(function (){
    $("#titlelink").attr("linktext",$("#titlelink").attr("href"));
    $("#titleInput").change(function(){
$("#titlelink").attr("href",($("#titlelink").attr("href")+$(this).val()));
});
        });
```

Here on document load I am saving href property to another attribute in same link.

And then I am adding change event listener to the input control. Whenever title text changes in input control the href attribute of the link will be changes accordingly.

Here instead of change event listener you can also use keypress event listener for input control.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just add the value on to the end?  Something like: href="/sites/203..&[Title]"